# Web Scraping Stock Ticker Price from Yahoo Finance using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to scrape Gold stock ticker from Yahoo! Finance.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

response = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GC=F?p=GC=F')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
gold_price = soup.findAll("div", class_='My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)')[2].find_all('p').text
```

Whenever I run this it returns: `list index out of range`.
When I do `print(len(ssoup))` it returns `4`.

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: Just leaving [this](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/) here

Comment: Thank you sir, but i dont see any methods for getting the headlines related to gold, which is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your expected output

Answer (score 1):

You can make a direct request to the yahoo server. To locate the query URL you need to open Network tab via `Dev tools (F12) -> Fetch/XHR -> find name: spark?symbols=` (refresh page if you don't see any), find the needed symbol, and see the response (preview tab) on the newly opened tab on the right.

You can make direct requests to all of these links if the request method is `GET` since `POST` methods are much more complicated.

You need `json` and `requests` library, no need for `bs4`. Note that making a lot of such requests might block your IP (*or set an IP rate limit*) or you won't get any response because their system might detect that it's a bot since the regular user won't make such requests to the server, repeatedly. So you need to figure out how to bypass it.

Update:
There's possibly a hard limit on how many requests can be made in an X period of time.

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Beautiful-Soup-4-Web-Scraping#main.py) (contains full JSON response):

```py
import requests, json

response = requests.get('https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/spark?symbols=GC%3DF&range=1d&interval=5m&indicators=close&includeTimestamps=false&includePrePost=false&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com&.tsrc=finance').text
data_1 = json.loads(response)

gold_price = data_1['spark']['result'][0]['response'][0]['meta']['previousClose']
print(gold_price)

# 1830.8
```

---

P.S. There's a blog about [scraping Yahoo! Finance Home Page](https://dev.to/dimitryzub) of mine, which is kind of relevant.