# How to load information from continuous scrolling websites for scraping using beautifulsoup?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, infinite-scroll

I need to collect all the data of nike shoes from https://www.nike.com/gb/w/mens-running-shoes-37v7jznik1zy7ok
When I try to scrape from beautifulsoup, I only get information of the first 24 products. Any help in solving this will be greatly appreciated.

```
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())
div_tags1 = soup.findAll("div", class_="product-grid css-195fkdt")
len(div_tags)
```

Comment: It's correct behavior because data loaded dynamically (*when you scroll the page*), `bs4` can't do that. That's why you only get 24 items, instead of 96. If you want to scrape all elements, you need to use `selenium` to scroll the page several times and then parse all data.

Comment: Additionally, you can parse the data by making a direct request to the nikecloud (*their API, server, or whatever it is*) and grab already structured data without parsing it (using `bs4`). To make it work: `Dev tools -> Network -> Fetch\XHR -> find "product" name in the list and click on it -> Headers tab -> Request URL`. Note, that it's a `POST` request, so you need to figure out how to make a `POST` request. I answered a similar question but [regarding the `GET` request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69912442/15164646). The process is a bit different but similar at the same time.